# Java how to add insert element at beginning of variable argument array?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have a function with string list argument and I want to  insert element at beginning of this string list argument so that I can pass it to other function as an argument , now when I try to follow adding ArrayList but the argArr have no such method ..

```
ArrayList.add(0,"foo");


private void A(String... argsArr)
{
   //insert element at beginning
   B(argArr); 
}
private void B(String... argsArr)
{
}
```

Comment: Use `List<String>` instead of `String...`.

Comment: `String... argsArr` is not a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), it is a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), i.e it is more like an array than a list.

Comment: @Turing85 It is, in fact, an array.

Comment: ok .. how can i add those elements into the beginning of the varargs

Comment: You can't. Arrays can't be resized. Lists can though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a variable arguments array, you could create a new array with the element inserted. For example, using streams:

```
private void a(String... argsArr) {
    String[] args2 = Stream.concat(Stream.of("foo"), Arrays.stream(args))
                           .toArray(String[]::new);
    b( args2 );
}
```

If you prefer, you can create a new array without streams. Here's an easy way that uses a temporary List.

```
private void a(String... argsArr) {
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    newList.add("foo");
    newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(argsArr));

    b(newList.toArray(new String[newList.size()]));
}
```

If you don't need a variable arguments array, you could use a List<> argument. It would be good form to insert the new element into a different list. The caller may provide a non-modifiable list, or may not want its list modified.

```
private void a2( List<String> args ) {

    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>( args );
    newList.add(0, "foo"); // <-- Extra O(n) time to shift elements over.

    b( newList );
}
```

You can improve the efficiency by a constant factor by not inserting at the beginning of an existing list.

```
private void a2( List<String> args ) {

    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>( );
    newList.add("foo"); 
    newList.addAll( args );

    b( newList );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String...` is a variable length array, **not** a `ArrayList`, thus `add(index,element)` is not available on your `argsArr` param.

You need to write some logic to achieve what you want. One possibility is listed below:

```
private void A(String... argsArr){
   List<String> list = Arrays.stream(argsArr).collect(Collectors.toList());
   list.add(0,"New_Element_To_Be_Added");
   B(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the array to a bigger array and set the 0th index:

```
int[] second = new int[args.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(args, 0, second, 1, args.length);
second[0] = val;
```

Since `varargs` is an array.